# what is this encoding: "\'ca\'fd\'cf\'d4\'bf\'a8\'b3\'df\'d1\'af\'bc\'db"?

Tags: unicode, cjk

I am reading a document in C# that is supposed to be in Chinese, but I am getting lines such as the following:

```
"}\htmlrtf {\f6 \htmlrtf0 \'ca\'fd\'cf\'d4\'bf\'a8\'b3\'df\'d1\'af\'bc\'db"
```

Can someone tell me what this encoding is, and how I can decode it?

Comment: That's the raw bytes. You need to set your editor to accept UTF-16, which is what Chinese typically uses.

Comment: thanks, but I would recognize raw byte as \x, not \'. I am reading the document in my code from a file, there is no editor involved. I can read other documents in Chinese just fine, but not this one.

Comment: they're not UTF-16. You can copy the byte sequence and convert to see with this tool https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: It is RTF (rich text format), predates the invention of Unicode and uses character sets.  Don't convert it yourself, use the RichTextBox class.  Assign the RTF property or use LoadFile(), read back the Text property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) is a 7-bit ASCII format (the [`\htmlrtf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203126.aspx) command is a Microsoft extension to the RTF format).

Inside of an RTF document, non-ASCII characters can be represented in one of two different ways:

1. charset-encoded to 8-bit bytes, and then each byte is escaped in `\'XX` format.

   This is what you are seeing in your document.  So, the hex sequence `\'ca\'fd\'cf\'d4\'bf\'a8\'b3\'df\'d1\'af\'bc\'db` is the escaped form of the byte sequence `0xCA 0xFD 0xCF 0xD4 0xBF 0xA8 0xB3 0xDF 0xD1 0xAF 0xBC 0xDB`.

   To convert that byte sequence to a Unicode string (which is what C# uses), you have to interpret the bytes using a codepage that is specified earlier in the RTF document (via an [`\ansi`, `\mac`, `\pc`, `pca`, or `\ansicpg` command](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading8) in the RTF document's header).

   For instance, the above byte sequence is the Unicode string `"数显卡尺询价"` when interpreted using either codepage 936 or 20936 (for Simplified Chinese).
2. Unicode codepoints are encoded as UTF-16, and then each codeunit is escaped in [`\uXXXX` format](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading9).